# How can I get address of variable using Valgrind API?

Tags: c++, linux, profiling, valgrind, memory-profiling

I've tried to modify Valgrind Lackey tool for getting addresses of array elements in my profiled program. I try to write simple memory access profiler, that stores in file two types of memory accesses: LOADs and STOREs. After getting that I want to calculate spatial and temporal localities.

I use Lackey with command line option --trace-mem=yes. In my opinion, there are two suitable functions for it: trace_load() and trace_store(), but when I've ran my profiler with test program (vector[100] * vector[100]), I got the same trace addresses for every array element in my log.

How can I fix it? (Sorry for my English)